# Excel task scheduler. I get the error "Microsoft Excel has stopped working"

Tags: vba, excel, scheduled-tasks

I am running the following macro on excel to create a list of files in a particular folder as Auto_Open

```
Option Explicit
Sub Auto_Open()

    Dim MyFolder As String
    Dim MyFile As String
    Dim NextRow As Long
    Dim MyDateTime As Date
    Dim MyDate As Date

MyFolder = "C:\Users\Folder\"

MyFile = Dir(MyFolder)


NextRow = 1
Do While Len(MyFile) > 0
    MyDateTime = FileDateTime(MyFolder & MyFile)
    MyDate = Int(MyDateTime)

If MyDate = Date Then
    Cells(NextRow, "A").Value = MyFolder & MyFile
    Cells(NextRow, "B").Value = MyDateTime

    NextRow = NextRow + 1
End If
    MyFile = Dir
Loop

Dim wb As Workbook
    Set wb = Workbooks.Add
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Copy Before:=wb.Sheets(1)
    wb.SaveAs ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & Format(Now, "yyyy-mm-dd") & "_FileList", FileFormat:=51
    wb.Close
    ThisWorkbook.Close SaveChanges:=False
End Sub
```

I scheduled to run the excel file containing this macro through the windows task scheduler daily. It creates an excel file as programmed and closes all the workbooks except the excel application. However, after that I get the error that "Microsoft Excel has stopped working".

Why is this happening? Any suggestions on how I can fix this?

Comment: What is on `Sheet1` - any buttons or controls? Why not create the new workbook earlier in the code and write the values directly to it?

Comment: Sheet 1 is empty. I can do try doing it that way

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. In task scheduler, under properties -> Settings, I unchecked the box that says "If the running task does not end when requested, force it to stop"

Stopped getting the error!